# Installing sphinx on a web hosting server

Tags: linux, sphinxsearch

I want to install sphinx search on a web-hosting server.
I'm on a Linux VPS with hostgator, but I never actually installed
anything on a remote server so this will be a first time for me.

If there's anyone here who installed sphinx it's really help me

I had some problems when using sphinx on my PC with the permissions
and the MySQL files, eventually I got it working on my PC.
Anyway, I'd me really grateful if anyone can help me with some questions

1. Do i need root access to install sphinx? I have root access to
   the server but I'd connect to it as a normal user since doing
   stuff as root is always less secure.
2. can anyone tell me by what user I need to execute the indexer and the search daemon?
   Should I use root access in order to this?
   when I did it as a normal user on my PC it gave me some trouble with the PID
   file and the log files.
3. last time I executed the search deamon I executed it as a normal user and it gave me some
   trouble, I created the folder /var/log/ for log files and did chmod 777 on it, but still when I
   executed the search daemon it created the PID file "searchd.pid" file but with no permissions for
   some reason, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sphinxsearch could be run fine from any user.
However by default the root rights are used in order to keep the logs in the /var/log.
So, if you reassign the log files in sphinx config to the some path accessible to the selected user, and also if you don't use the port to serve from the privileged to root port range - it is absolutely no caveats to run sphinx from an unprivileged user.

(btw - you can configure --wigh-syslog, and then use 'searchd_log=syslog' and 'query_log=syslog' - to totally avoid the log place question)